# I am getting error in mysql create function statement

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PortName;
CREATE FUNCTION PortName(port INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(3) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE x VARCHAR(3);
    CASE port;
       WHEN 996 THEN SET x = 'RP';
       WHEN 995 THEN SET x = 'IA';
       WHEN 990 THEN SET x = 'K1';
       WHEN 989 THEN SET x = 'K2';
       WHEN 988 THEN SET x = 'K3';
       WHEN 986 THEN SET x = 'NG';
       WHEN 985 THEN SET x = 'NW';
       WHEN 984 THEN SET x = 'N2';
       WHEN 983 THEN SET x = 'N3';
       ELSE SET x = 'NA';
    RETURN x;
END;
```

Comment: You shouldn't have `;` after `CASE PORT`

Comment: And you're missing `END CASE`.

Comment: I don't see delimiters being set and you could publish how you are running  this script (ide,command line etc);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be `;` between `CASE port` and the `WHEN` statements. And you need `END CASE;` at the end.

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS PortName;
CREATE FUNCTION PortName(port INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(3) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
    DECLARE x VARCHAR(3);
    CASE port
       WHEN 996 THEN SET x = 'RP';
       WHEN 995 THEN SET x = 'IA';
       WHEN 990 THEN SET x = 'K1';
       WHEN 989 THEN SET x = 'K2';
       WHEN 988 THEN SET x = 'K3';
       WHEN 986 THEN SET x = 'NG';
       WHEN 985 THEN SET x = 'NW';
       WHEN 984 THEN SET x = 'N2';
       WHEN 983 THEN SET x = 'N3';
       ELSE SET x = 'NA';
    END CASE;
    RETURN x;
END;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html for the syntax of `CASE`.

Comment: i am still getting error

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

Comment: Did you use a `DELIMTER` directive before defining the function?

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I just forgot to use DELIMITER.